# Scanf after for loop

Tags: c, scanf

I don't understand why if I insert a letter the program executes the `printf`'s after the for loop without letting me insert a value for the `scanf` after the for loop.

```
    int main()
    {
    float ascissa, ordinata, d, dis, a[50];
    int i=0, j, count = 0;
    for(;;){
        printf("Inserisci ascissa: (oppure inserisci una lettera per terminare): ");
        if(scanf("%f", &ascissa) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Inserisci ordinata: ");
        scanf("%f", &ordinata);
        punto p1 = creaPunto(ascissa, ordinata);
        printf("Inserisci ascissa: ");
        scanf("%f", &ascissa);
        printf("Inserisci ordinata: ");
        scanf("%f", &ordinata);
        punto p2 = creaPunto(ascissa, ordinata);
        dis = distanza(p1, p2);
        a[i]=dis;
        i++;
    }
    printf("Inserisci d: ");
    scanf("%f", &d);
    for(j=0; j<i; j++)
        if(a[j]<d)
            count++;
    printf("Coppie che hanno distanza minore di d: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: `scanf` will block if you enter a letter when a `float` is expected: it remains in the input buffer until you take steps to remove it. If you check the return value from each `scanf` which should be `1` you can test if the input was accepted.

Comment: `scanf()` doesn't so much _block_, @WeatherVane, as it _doesn't block_ (and returns immediately) because there is (still) a letter in the input which can't be converted into a number.  The design of the user interface needs fixing, as does the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I meant the letter blocks the input, as you know.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you enter a letter to break the `for` loop, the value entered is remains unconsumed in the stdin buffer. `%f` doesn't consume the input because of format matching failure.

You need to clear any such unconsumed input yourself. For example, you can have a function to clear:

```
void clear_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

and call it:

```
printf("Inserisci ascissa: (oppure inserisci una lettera per terminare): ");
if(scanf("%f", &ascissa) != 1) {
    clear_stdin();
    break;
}
```

Similarly, you need to error check & clear all scanf calls.

Related: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)